# Flutter typedMiddleware

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, middleware, flutter-redux

I am kinda new to flutter and trying out the flutter redux library  but I am stuck with having a proper list of middlewares.

```
import 'package:flutter_app/incrementButtonScreen/IncrementButtonActions.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/incrementButtonScreen/IncrementButtonLogicStates.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/incrementButtonScreen/IncrementButtonState.dart';
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';

List<Middleware<IncrementButtonState>> createIncrementButtonStoreMiddleware = [
  TypedMiddleware<IncrementButtonState, Increment>(createIncrement("typed")),
  createIncrement("normal")
];

Middleware<IncrementButtonState> createIncrement(String logger) {
  return (Store store, action, NextDispatcher next) {
    print('\n ACTION $logger : ${new DateTime.now()}: $action');
    // some api call happening here and passing the APi call result next
    next(IncrementButtonLogicIncrementState(220, 15.0));
  };
}
```

the issue is, I only get the logs from the normal middleWare but never from typed version. I am trying to rework the counter example and dispatching action `class Increment{}` on fab click `store.dispatch(Increment);`
I am creating my store here:

```
Store createIncrementButtonStore() {
  return new Store<IncrementButtonState>(_counterReducer,
      initialState: IncrementButtonState.initial(), middleware: createIncrementButtonStoreMiddleware);
}
```

when I replace `TypedMiddleware<IncrementButtonState, Increment>` with `TypedMiddleware<IncrementButtonState, dynamic>` then I get the it works

```
ACTION typed : 2018-08-06 12:04:45.778293: Increment
     ACTION normal : 2018-08-06 12:04:45.778411: Instance of 'IncrementButtonLogicIncrementState'
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of searching, I found that I was dispatching `Increment` which is eqivalent to Increment.class in java I believe, after dispatching `Increment()` it works fine